# R k-means algorithm custom centers

Tags: r, k-means

I have a 2D dataset imported in R - `(x,y)` coordinates. I want to perform k-means clustering on this dataset, but I would like to set concrete coordinates to be initial centers. For example, I would like to start with 5 centers with their values to be `(5, 10), (3, 8), (46, 22), (87, 66), (39, 41)` .

I saw a centers parameter in kmeans function, but I do not understand how to set my values to be centeres.

```
kmeans(data, centers = ...) # what to set here?
```

Comment: probably something like `kmeans( data, centers=matrix(c(5, 10, 3, 8, 46, 22, 87, 66, 39, 41), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you for this question. Indeed, in R documentation it is very badly explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `centers` parameter takes either an integer `k`, in which case `k` random points from `data` are chosen as initial centers, or a matrix of initial centers, with as many columns as `data`. Try this:

```
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
                 matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
kmeans(x,centers=3)
kmeans(x,centers=x[1:3,])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a `matrix`, here is a quick example:

```
data = matrix(c(1.1,1,0.97,0.99,0.95,0.8,0.91,2.1,2,2.4,4.1,4.4,4.5,3.9,1.5,1.2,1.7,2.6,2.7,2.44), ncol=2)
```

Now let's mention 2 starting points `C1 (x1=1,y1=3)` and `C2 (x2=2,y2=4)` (even if there are obviously 3 groups):

```
km = kmeans(data, centers=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),ncol=2))
```

Some plotting after applying the algo:
    df = transform(as.data.frame(data), group=as.character(km$cluster))
    library(ggplot2)

```
ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2, color=group)) + geom_point()
```

[image]