# Set static centers for kmeans in R

Tags: r, k-means, geosphere

I want to group a list of Long and Lats (my_long_lats) based on pre determined center points (my_center_Points).

When I run:-

```
k <- kmeans(as.matrix(my_long_lats), centers = as.matrix(my_center_Points))
```

`k$centers` **does not equal** my_center_Points.

I assume k-means has adjusted my center points to the optimal center. But what I need is for my_center_Points to not change and group my_long_lats around them.

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605911/r-k-means-algorithm-custom-centers)
they talk about setting initial centers but How do I set centers that wont change once I run the k means? Or is there a better clustering algorithm for this?

I could even settle for minimizing the movement of the centers.

I still have a lot to learn in R, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need a distance metric instead, for example the Euclidean distance between points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the calculation using the `geosphere` library to properly compute the distance from latitude and longitude.

The variable `closestcenter` is the result which identifies the closest center to each point.

```
#define random data
centers<-data.frame(x=c(44,44, 50, 50), y=c(44, 50, 44, 50))
pts<-data.frame(x=runif(50, 40, 55), y=runif(50, 40, 55))

#allocate space
distance<-matrix(-1, nrow = length(pts$x), ncol= length(centers$x))

library(geosphere)
#calculate the dist matrix - the define centers to each point
#columns represent centers and the rows are the data points
dm<-apply(data.frame(1:length(centers$x)), 1, function(x){ replace(distance[,x], 1:length(pts$x), distGeo(centers[x,], pts))})

#find the column with the smallest distance
closestcenter<-apply(dm, 1, which.min)

#color code the original data for verification
colors<-c("black", "red", "blue", "green")
plot(pts , col=colors[closestcenter], pch=19)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this method better fits my needs, Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`centers` are automatically evaluated after performing `kmeans` clustering. In fact, determining `centers` is a vital point in order to divide into cluster groups. Couple of options I can think that can help you.

1. Limit `iter.max`. You can set it to just `1` in `kmeans` function call. This will not guarantee to keep centers fixed but changes will be less if you are dealing with large data sets.
2. Use of dummy data. You can add many `dummy` data in your actual data sets around chosen `centers`. This will put extra weight towards along pre-determined `centers`. Most likely `centers` will remain unchanged.

Comment: #2 too seems like it will work well for me. Thank you!